# Xcode 8.1 swift 3 take forever to compile this code

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, swift3, xcode8

I have this class in a project which previously use swift 2.3. When i migrated the project to swift 3, xcode took forever to compile and i saw it stuck at this class. I can not build the whole project because of this class. Is there a way to modify this class so the project can be built, it took Xcode forever to compile this piece of code. If i removed several properties from MyClass, Xcode will quickly compile again. Anyone has any idea on how to solve this problem?

```
import Foundation

class MyClass: NSObject {

    var id: String = ""
    var uid: String = ""
    var uname: String = ""
    var fname: String = ""
    var txt: String = ""
    var hay: Float = 0
    var flag = false
    var long: Double = 0
    var lat: Double = 0
    var altitude: Double = 0
    var course: Double = 0
    var speed: Double = 0
    var lname: String = ""
    var city: String = ""
    var country: String = ""
    var sublocal: String = ""
    var subarea: String = ""
    var thumb: String = ""
    var trash = false
    var date: Double = 0
    var updated: Double = 0
    var furl: String = ""

    func toAnyObject() -> Any {
        return [
            "id": id,
            "uid": uid,
            "uname": uname,
            "fname": fname,
            "txt": txt,
            "hay": hay,
            "flag": flag,
            "long": long,
            "lat": lat,
            "altitude": altitude,
            "course": course,
            "speed": speed,
            "lname": lname,
            "city": city,
            "country": country,
            "sublocal": sublocal,
            "trash": trash,
            "subarea": subarea,
            "thumb": thumb,
            "date": date,
            "updated": updated,
            "furl": furl
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely you want to annotate the return of `toAnyObject()` as `[String : Any]`?

Comment: i tried that but no sucess, i notice SourceKitSer  process use alot of CPU if i try to compile this code
PID   COMMAND      %CPU  TIME  
2239  SourceKitSer 197.6 00:35.13 6/2

Comment: I tested this on another mac with xcode 8.1 swift 3, I have created a fresh new project with only MyClass and it still take forever to compile. Very strange. You can copy/paste my code and try by yourself

Comment: Unclear what you want from Stack Overflow in this situation. File a bug with Apple! You can file on bugs.swift.org and count on a rapid response (at least that has been my experience).

Comment: @matt i thought someone on Stackoverflow might know how to fix this problem

Comment: I don't quite see what you mean by "fix". You've clearly found a bug in the language / compiler. What would a "fix" be? Don't use Swift? Obviously you should just try to avoid big dictionary literals of the sort you are using. You don't need us to tell you that!

Comment: @matt thank you for your comment but it not very helpful and does not solve my problem. Just for clarification, i have this class in a project which previously use swift 2.3. When i migrated the project to swift 3, xcode took forever to compile and i saw it stuck at this class. So the problem to fix here is i can not build the whole project because of this class. What i want to fix is to modify this class so the project can be built. If you can not help then please ignore my question :)

Comment: @hoang as a side note. Are you absolutely certain that you need those as `vars`? It seems unlikely that you would ever update the `id`, `uid`, `uname`, etc... If they're not updated then use `let`. In fact, you should use `let` by default and only ever change to `var` if the compiler tells you it's needed.

Comment: It isn't related to your code. After updating to xcode 8.1 even sample empty projects of xcode itself take forever to deploy to the phone but everything works just fine with the simulator.

Comment: @Fogmeister, yes we have several `init()` that i have removed for the simplicity of the question so we need those `vars`

Comment: Delete all the Apple ID keys from your keychain except one. I had 2k of them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite without the big dictionary literal. So:

```
func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    var d = [String:Any]()
    d["id"] = id
    d["uid"] = uid
    // ... and so on ...
    return d
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing so already adding a `-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies` compiler flag to your project will list the time required to compile each function. That can be a useful way to identify what exactly is slow in your build. (See http://irace.me/swift-profiling or https://thatthinginswift.com/debug-long-compile-times-swift/).

In your case the compiler is probably struggling to determine the type of your dictionary literal. Looking at each key and value and then trying to find the most appropriate common type for all of them. If you specified a type then I expect the compiler will only need to verify that your literal matches that type and compile much more quickly:

```
let result: [String: Any] = ["id": id, ...]
return result
```

Comment: i tried this but its not working, Matt solution works: `var d = [String:Any]()
    d["id"] = id
    d["uid"] = uid
    // ... and so on ...
    return d`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the compiler slows down when you do implicit typing.  If you Explicitly add the type information then the compiler will not need to calculate it.  I can see that the properties of your class mostly have type information but not all of them.  In your toAnyObject method, it seems like you want your object represented as a dictionary, yet you are converting it to type Any.

You are making a dictionary literal and offering no type information. Explicitly casting with "as" can help a lot.

When you convert something to type Any, Objective-C interprets that as id.  Normally a swift dictionary would be bridged to an NSDictionary for Objective-c, but you are forcing it to be of type Any.  What reason would the compiler have to bridge this to an NSDictionary?  It probably boxes it since it thinks it is a struct and objective-c can't use swift structs.

Try to not confuse the compiler.