# Xcode 12 slow build one file

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a data structure in my Xcode project similar to this:

```
struct Group: {
  let name: String
  var items: [Thing]
}

struct Thing: {
  let description: String
  let variants: [Thing]?
}

var data: [Group] = 
    [Group(name: "Group 1",
          items: [Thing(description: "Thing 1", variants: nil),
                  Thing(description: "Thing 2", variants: nil),
                  ... ]),
     Group(name: "Group 2",
          items: [Thing(description: "AnotherThing 1", variants: [Thing(description: "Variant Thing1)",
                                                                  Thing(description: "Variant Thing2)",
                                                                  ... ]),
                  Thing(description: "AnotherThing 2", variants: [Thing(description: "Variant Thing 101"),
                                                                  Thing(description: "Variant Thing 102"),
                                                                  ... ]),
      ... ])]
```

In total there are about 10 Group's containing about 3200 Thing's; the Thing's are spread about equally in "items" arrays and "variants" arrays.

Xcode takes from 3 to 5 minutes to compile this one file. What can I do to reduce this to a reasonable time?

Aside: In addition to being slow to compile, this data structure is making the Xcode profiler go bonkers. Fairly often, the profiler will eat up all of the swap space and crash the machine.

Comment: I have no idea what to do about the structure but what I wonder what would happen if you stored this as json instead and then decoded it in runtime? Compilation would be instant I assume but I don’t know if the decoding would be an issue.

Comment: I'll give this a try, but I'd really rather have a solution for the structure. Or at least understand what the problem is.

Comment: Just use successive appends, not big literals.

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768971/compiling-large-array-literal-in-xcode-8-2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440977/xcode-8-1-swift-3-take-forever-to-compile-this-code. Basically the compiler hates big literals so just don’t write them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't do it exactly like matt suggested but his advice put me onto a way to do it and not be too ugly.

```
struct Thing: {
  let description: String
  var variants: [Thing]?
}
            
struct Group: {
  let name: String
  var items: [Thing]
}
        
let group1Things: [Thing] = [
  Thing(description: "Thing 1", variants: nil),
  Thing(description: "Thing 2", variants: nil),
  ... ]
        
let group1: Group = Group(name: "Group 1", items: group1Things)
        
let group2Things: [Thing] = [
  Thing(description: "AnotherThing 1", variants: [Thing(description: "Variant Thing1)",
                                                  Thing(description: "Variant Thing2)",
                                                  ... ]),
  Thing(description: "AnotherThing 2", variants: [Thing(description: "Variant Thing 101"),
                                                  Thing(description: "Variant Thing 102"),
                                                  ... ]

let group2: Group = Group(name: "Group 2", items: group2Things)
        
let data: [Group] = [group1, group2, ...]
```

This got the compile time down from 3-5 minutes to 30 seconds. I can live with that. I could probably get it down further by breaking out the "variants" arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the assignment to

```
var data: [Group] = [Group(name: "Group 1", ....
```

In my experience, these slowdowns are mostly due to type inference, and specifying the type explicitly helps a lot.

If that doesn't work, follow the advice given by Joakim Danielson.

Comment: I've actually tried this and it didn't help. I'll edit the original post accordingly. There's no question that type inference is the problem because I tried the Xfrontend flags that you see here and there; I just can't figure out how to fix it.